# compare values from dictionary with list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

i have a dictionary like this and i want to compare it with a list

```
dic=
{0: 0,
 1: 1200,
 2: 2400,
 3: 1800,
 4: 2400,
 5: 2400,
 6: 1200,
 7: 1800,
 8: 2400}

list = [0,2,5,7]
```

How can I create sum over the list with the values from the dictionary?

sum = 0+2400+2400+1800

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

and how is it if I want to compare it with another dictionary instead of the list? so I need a sum for 0 and 1

```
dic2=
{Route1: [0, 2, 5, 7]
 Route2: [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 4}
```

Comment: Could you expand upon the second case and clarify what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `dict.get` passing `0` as default value for each key in the list, then call `sum` over it:

```py
>>> sum(dic.get(key, 0) for key in list)
Out[5]: 6600
```

On a side note, don't use `list` as a variable name as it will mask built-in `list` constructor.

Or, you can use `itemgetter` from `operator`, and pass unpacked list, finally use `sum` for these values. Be noted that you'll get value error if some keys in list doesn't exist in dictionary:

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sum(itemgetter(*list)(dic))
Out[8]: 6600
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is:

```
dic = {0: 0,
       1: 1200,
       2: 2400,
       3: 1800,
       4: 2400,
       5: 2400,
       6: 1200,
       7: 1800,
       8: 2400}

dic2 = {0: [0, 2, 5, 7],
        1: [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 4]}

results = {}
for key, value in dic2.items():
    total = 0
    for i in value:
        new_value = dic[i]
        total += new_value

    results.update({f'Route{key+1}': total})

print(results)
```

I suggest you always write the simplest code possible. Unnecessarily complex code, is bad code:

> Simple is better than complex.

From the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you can use this:

```
dic= {  0: 0,
        1: 1200,
        2: 2400,
        3: 1800,
        4: 2400,
        5: 2400,
        6: 1200,
        7: 1800,
        8: 2400
    }

lst = [0,2,5,7]

res = sum(map(lambda x: dic[x], lst))

print(res)

# 6600
```

And for the second case, use list comprehension:

```
dic= {  0: 0,
        1: 1200,
        2: 2400,
        3: 1800,
        4: 2400,
        5: 2400,
        6: 1200,
        7: 1800,
        8: 2400
    }

dic2 = {'Route1': [0, 2, 5, 7],
        'Route2': [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 4]}

lst2 = [sum(map(lambda x: dic[x], dic2[i])) for i in dic2]

print(lst2)

# [6600, 10200]
```

Or dict comprehension:

```
dic= {  0: 0,
        1: 1200,
        2: 2400,
        3: 1800,
        4: 2400,
        5: 2400,
        6: 1200,
        7: 1800,
        8: 2400
    }

dic2 = {'Route1': [0, 2, 5, 7],
        'Route2': [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 4]}

dic3 = {k: sum(map(lambda x: dic[x], dic2[k])) for k in dic2}

print(dic3)

# {'Route1': 6600, 'Route2': 10200}
```